# How to express the concept "la ficelle est trop grosse"?

Tags: word-choice, phrase-requests

There is a concept embedded in the French expression ***la ficelle est trop grosse*** (literally 'the string is too thick') to describe a subterfuge that is doomed to fail, because the disguise is too obvious. The thick string is evidently a metaphor, as in an object that has been poorly put together, for a flaw in the makeup that is bound to be noticed.

A quick search on this phrase turned nothing: French dictionaries seem strangely oblivious and I did not see any English equivalent.

I could think of a conceptual opposite with *seamless*, but is there some expression in English that expresses such an idea?

Comment: There is an idiom that's the opposite of "seamless": "the seams are showing" that might work. But its use is much broader than describing subterfuges that are doomed to fail—it's more usually used to describe something (such as a coalition) that was put together hastily and is about to fall apart.

Comment: I found *[«la ficelle est un peu grosse»](http://www.linternaute.com/expression/langue-francaise/16582/la-ficelle-est-un-peu-grosse/) here*, with an etymology which makes sense, and a suggested translation *[at reverso.net](http://dictionary.reverso.net/french-english/la%20ficelle%20est%20un%20peu%20grosse)* which accords with my initial thoughts, *“you can see right through it”*. I can make this into an answer if you like ...

Comment: 'The approach is too broad-brush'

( {[ODO](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/broad-brush)} [broad-brush approach] An approach characterized by a lack of detail or subtlety)

covers the lack of subtlety angle, but not the other details.

Comment: Proverbs 1:17 has an early form: 'How useless to spread a net where every bird can see it!.' [NIV] {[BibleHub](http://biblehub.com/proverbs/1-17.htm)}

Comment: In French, la ficelle est grosse or trop grosse means one can "see through something" , literally strings (puppet) are visible.  To see through what a person is trying to do. In some contexts, one might say: ***their slip is showing*** in English. You can tell what they are up to.

Comment: @WillCrawford That coud indeed make an answer?

Answer (score 3):

With many idioms, it's a difficult task to translate directly, however, in this case the meaning is fairly simple.

The phrase *[“la ficelle est un peu grosse”](http://www.linternaute.com/expression/langue-francaise/16582/la-ficelle-est-un-peu-grosse/)* literally means *“the string is a little thick”,* in other words, it’s too readily visible for the willing suspension of disbelief. There is a suggested translation as *[**you can see right through it**](http://dictionary.reverso.net/french-english/la%20ficelle%20est%20un%20peu%20grosse)* at reverso.net.

I would just use that, although the phrase *you can see the strings* has appeared in English here and there, for example in *[Watchmen](https://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Watchmen)*:

> **Laurie Juspeczyk:** Is that what you are? The most powerful thing in the universe and you're just a puppet following a script?
>   **Doctor Manhattan:** We're all puppets, Laurie. I'm just a puppet who can see the strings.

I vaguely recalling hearing this earlier in life. We certainly have a lot of common(ish) idioms on the same lines, such as *you can see the joins*, or references to *being able to see the man behind the curtain* (a reference to *The Wizard of Oz*, for anyone not raised on BBC2).

*Ah, les Français. Quel finesse.*

Comment: I don't think there is much finesse here at all. We have thousands of similar things in English. You have quoted a good passage but it won't work in translating  the phrase.

Comment: I thought it would show that, depending on the context, they might be able to transliterate and get away with it...

Comment: Yes, it's a good find.

Comment: Consider _it sticks out like a sore thumb_ (suggests [Larousse online](http://larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais-anglais/ficelle/33507)). But with most examples in Eng. dict., I was surprised (not a native speaker) to see it's mostly about people standing out in a crowd etc. and rarely about sth. like a scheme. I thought it was the swelling/color, no, it's how you hold it.  Anyways, if it's useful s.o. can use it. I note you quote the phrase as it appears in the dictionary i.e. ["un peu grosse"](http://larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/ficelle/33564/locution) and not "trop grosse", indeed...

Comment: +1, that is a good idiom for a lot of "it's *painfully* obvious" cases. As you note, though, it is usually reserved for the more .. *éclaté* situations. If it's about a fairly direct subterfuge, you could try something like *he couldn't lie his way out of a paper bag*, or similar.